# Import/export xml file to sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on MVC4,i am stuck with solution where i have to provide tables backup as xml format. what i want is based upon some parameters if data is present in particular tables i have to get those data then generate xml for that data.
eg. I have 3 tables

Table A with column FirstName,MiddleName,LastName
Table B with column FirstName,LastName
Table C with column FirstName,MiddleName,LastName

and parameters would firstname,middlename,lastname

Eg : If i want get all records with firstname and lastname parameters ....so if in above 3 tables firstname and lastname match.

1.only those record per table should be converted into xml per table

I have search for  'for xml,raw,auto,path' etc... but could get to result.and which one i should use ?

Because after making xml files per table ...i have to restore those files to sql server?

Can anyone suggest me how can i achieve this functionality in best approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using LINQ to XML?

A sample could be:

```
XElement xTableA = new XElement
    (
        "TableA",
        TableA
        .Where(x=>x.FirstName == firstname && x.LastName == lastname)
        .Select
        (
            x=>
            new XElement
            (
                "Row", 
                new XElement("FirstName",x.FirstName), 
                new XElement("MiddleName",x.MiddleName), 
                new XElement("LastName",x.LastName)
            )
        );

XElement xTableB = new XElement
    (
        "TableB",
        TableB
        .Where(x=>x.FirstName == firstname && x.LastName == lastname)
        .Select
        (
            x=>
            new XElement
            (
                "Row", 
                new XElement("FirstName",x.FirstName), 
                new XElement("MiddleName",x.MiddleName), 
                new XElement("LastName",x.LastName)
            )
        );

XElement xTableC = new XElement
    (
        "TableC",
        TableC
        .Where(x=>x.FirstName == firstname && x.LastName == lastname)
        .Select
        (
            x=>
            new XElement
            (
                "Row", 
                new XElement("FirstName",x.FirstName), 
                new XElement("MiddleName",x.MiddleName), 
                new XElement("LastName",x.LastName)
            )
        );

xTableA.Save(filenameA);
xTableB.Save(filenameB);
xTableC.Save(filenameC);
```

This way you have three xml files with your requested data ready to import...

Comment: ok..thanks.. i can try this one.. so it will generate correct xml file to be imported into sql  ?

Comment: In order to answer that i need to know what is "correct" in your case. If you update your question with a sample expected xml, i can update my answer to fulfill this.

Comment: Sir problem is i have around 30+ tables and each tables have lots of column.. So first i don't think its good option to write all table and column one by one.. :(.. and for type of table/ data i have created sql fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/edd08... so there are many tables like this...

Comment: You could probably do it with a generics function, but it beats me, sorry

Comment: @ jyparask  Sir i am getting error when i try to run your code...i am getting error where you mentioned table name 'TableA'..error is 'its type but used as variable'.. am i missing something